# Автосборка новым компилятором в старом TFS

Tags: .net, tfs

Подскажите, а можно ли настроить автосборку в старой версии TFS (2013), что бы она могла без проблем собирать код из свежей VS(2017)?

Answer (score 0):

Да.

1. Ставите на машину с билд агентом нужную версию Framework
2. В Хранилище кода помещаете PowerShell скрипт вида:

   dotnet build -c $args[0]
3. Добавляете шаг запуска PowerShell скрипта.
4. У шага указываете путь до скрипта, что-то вида:

$(build.sourcesDirectory)/PS Scripts/dotnet_build.ps1

5. В качестве аргументов указываете путь к решению.

Все. Если надо настроить путь куда дропать результат, в какой конфигурации собирать и т.д., то это тоже можно сделать через аргументы запуска, в повершельном скрипте обрабатываете аргументы [1] и т.д. А нужные значения указываете в аргументах запуска. Можно, конечно, все в скрипте сразу прописать, но вам тогда придется для каждого билда/проекта свои скрипты писать.